# How do I perform range queries on an immutable Map?

Tags: immutable.js

Is there an easy way to perform range queries (e.g. get me all k,v pairs with keys between 50 and 100) on immutable maps with number keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one of two ways. You can either:

1. Iterate through the entire contents of the map and filter out values that you are not interested in.
2. Iterate from min to max and extract all values from the map into a new map

Unfortunately there is not a method built into ImmutableJS that will do this for you.

Here are the bits of code to help you along:

### Init

```
map = Immutable.Map([ [ 10, 'a' ], [ 20, 'b' ], [ 5, 'c' ], [ 100, 'd' ] ])
min = 0
max = 10
```

### method 1

```
map.filter((_, key) => key >= min && key <= max)
```

### method 2

```
let range = Array.apply(0, Array(max - min + 1)).map((_, index) => index + min);
return range.reduce((acc, key) => {
  return map.has(key) ?
    acc.set(key, map.get(key)) :
    acc;
}, Immutable.Map())
```

https://observablehq.com/@alexrass/extract-range-from-immutable-map